# FreeMarker: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to a sequence

Tags: java, freemarker

I understand that the same question already been here. But unfortunately it not helps me to solve my problem. I have HashSet in my FreeMarker template. I would like to show size of the HashSet on the view. I have the following for this:

```
 <td>${repo.getRepoWords().size()}</td>
```

Method getRepoWords is:

```
 public HashSet getRepoWords() {
     return repoWords;
 }
```

As the result I see this exception

> FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!):
> For "." left-hand operand: Expected a hash, but this has evaluated to
> a sequence (wrapper: f.t.SimpleSequence): ==> repo.getRepoWords() [in
> template "repositories/detail.ftl" at line 24, column 23] ---- FTL
> stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at:
> ${repo.getRepoWords().size()} [in template "repositories/detail.ftl"
> at line 24, column 21] ~ Reached through: #nested [in template
> "layouts/common.ftl" in macro "page" at line 20, column 1] ~ Reached
> through: @c.page title="Главная страница" [in template
> "repositories/detail.ftl" at line 2, column 1] ---- Java stack trace
> (for programmers): ---- freemarker.core.NonHashException: [...
> Exception message was already printed; see it above ...] at
> freemarker.core.Dot._eval(Dot.java:48) at
> freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:83) at
> freemarker.core.MethodCall._eval(MethodCall.java:58) at
> freemarker.core.Expression.eval(Expression.java:83) at

Can I use the size() method for a HashSet in a FreeMarker template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you to do use `?size` like below.Please check the [Document](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_size)

```
${repo.repoWords?size}
```